# Random Number Generation with Well44497a in C++

Tags: c++, random, generator, nsnumber, montecarlo

Sorry to bother again, but as I am new C++ I am having a lot of weird and silly problems.

I am programing a MCMC method. I read in this forum that the [WELL RNG](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~panneton/WELLRNG.html) was a good alternative to generate random numbers so I am trying to make it work. So here the questions:

1. I am compiling the "Well44497a.c" within my c++ project without further modifications. It compiled. Is that right or should I make any change?
2. I am using the following scheme inside my code but it is just generating a cycle of 3 RN

SOLVED: The problem was that InitWELLRNG44497a(state) should be placed outside the function. I was re initiating the generator every time I was generating a sample. For the whole run the generator has to be initialized just once.

```
    int* sampler(PARAMETERS) { //this function returns a sample

    int k;

    unsigned int state[1391];

    for (k = 0; k < 1391; ++k) 
    {
        state[k] = k;
    }

    InitWELLRNG44497a(state); //THIS SHOULD GO ON THE CALLER FUNCTION NOT HERE

    double value_first = valuate(first_state); // this function valuates one of two possible states
    double value_second = valuate(second_state); 

    double rand_number = WELLRNG44497a()

    if(rand_number > value_first / (value_first + value_second))
       return second_state;
    else
       return first_state;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your whole code? You've only shown one call to the RNG.

Comment: thanks, I added more or less a basic scratch of the function. I hope is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function appears to initialise the `state` array with the same values every time you call your `sampler()` function. The idea of the `state` array is that it holds the current state of the random number generator, and that you don't fiddle with the contents of `state` between calls to the RNG.

Make the `state` array global in your program, initialise it once, and don't touch it after initialisation.